# Update/Iterate over embedded Array MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a document structure like so:

```
{   
  data: null,
  subArray: [{
    key: 'a',
    subData: [] 
  }, {
    key: 'b',
    subData: []
  }] 
}
```

I will receive an array containing subArray `keys`, like: `['a', 'b']

I want to iterate over the `subArray` to push a value to `subData`, so that when `subArray` is `['a','b']`, my data will now be like:

```
{   
  data: null,
  subArray: [{
    key: 'a',
    subData: ['dataToPush'] 
  }, {
    key: 'b',
    subData: ['dataToPush']
  }] 
}
```

I have this query to do that:

```
update({_id:"...", "subArray.key":{"$in":['a','b']},
       {'$addToSet':{'subArray.$.subData':'...'}}})
```

Thinking that `$in` will let me loop through my `subArray`.
But I realize this does not work because `$in` gets the elements that match the elements in the array, so I will get my data but not iterate over my subArray.

Is it possible to complete this with a specific selector/modifier combo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not with multiple keys. For one key `"a"`, you could use a query like

```
db.test.update({ "subArray.key" : "a" }, { "$push" : { "subArray.$.subData" : "dataToPush" } })
```

but the $ positional operator can only be used for a single match in one update. You could do one update like the above per key, or retrieve the document, modify it based on all of the keys, then save over the original.